# How to test a value is rendered in Go.js

Tags: gojs

In Jest, after loading in the data into the `nodeDataArray`, how to I test that `go.TextBlock` is returning the right value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a way to identify the particular **TextBlock** in the **Node** that you want to check.  This is especially true if there are multiple TextBlocks.  In the example below I've given the TextBlock the **name** "TB".

This is a complete stand-alone example.  Instead of depending on Jest specifically, I have put the testing code into a function called later by **setTimeout**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minimal GoJS Sample</title>
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2023 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:600px"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
  <script id="code">
const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

const myDiagram =
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    { "undoManager.isEnabled": true });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",
    $(go.Shape,
      { fill: "white" },
      new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      { name: "TB", margin: 8 },
      new go.Binding("text"))
  );

myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[
  { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
  { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
  { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
  { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" }
],
[
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 2, to: 2 },
  { from: 3, to: 4 },
  { from: 4, to: 1 }
]);

setTimeout(() => {
  myDiagram.nodes.each(node => {
    const textblock = node.findObject("TB");
    if (textblock && textblock.text !== node.data.text) {
      alert(`Node ${node.key}'s TextBlock has wrong text: "${textblock.text}" instead of "${node.data.text}"`);
    }
  })
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```